# Use of Swing to create a digital clock

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, jframe

So, I was trying to create a simple digital clock using Swing. Its compiles just fine, the IDE that I use, Netbeans, says there are no compilation errors, etc.
However, when I run the code, I just get an empty frame without any text on it, in this context, the running time. Could someone tell me where I could have gone wrong?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;

public class DigitalTimer extends JFrame{
    JLabel msgbox;

public DigitalTimer(){
    super("Digital Clock");
    setSize(450,150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel clkpanel = new JPanel();
    msgbox = new JLabel();
    Font timefont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD,24);
    msgbox.setFont(timefont);

    clkpanel.add(msgbox);
    Timer refresher = new Timer(1000, new Listener());
    refresher.start();
    setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[]args){
 DigitalTimer dTimer;
        dTimer = new DigitalTimer();
    }

  class Listener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


   Calendar calendar;
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour;
            hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min;
        min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sec;
            sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    msgbox.setText(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: you never add `clkpanel` to the frames content.

Comment: Additionally to Timothy's comment. The `JPanel` you create is currently redundant for this problem, just add `msgbox` to your `JFrame`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Umm..doesn't the statement
 clkpanel.add(msgbox); add the content to the frames? Or, would I have to assign it in a different way?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Yep, sorry my bad, I forgot to include add(clkpanel) before adding the content to it. Thank you!

Comment: @d.j.brown Yeah, after parsing through it, I realised there were a few inefficiencies. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @AbdullahZameek is your problem soved now? (then add an answer and accept it). On more advice for future: do not extent JPanel, just use it!